# InfluxDB: INTO with multiple measurement

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to write aggregated result from two measurements into a single measurement.

I found on documentation that you can write multiple matching measurements with `:MEASUREMENT` keyword in [INTO query](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#the-into-clause). Like

```
SELECT * INTO "copy_NOAA_water_database"."autogen".:MEASUREMENT FROM 
"NOAA_water_database"."autogen"./.*/
```

What I'm trying to do is aggregate from multiple measurements and write result to a single measurement.

```
SELECT mean("water_level") INTO 
"copy_NOAA_water_database"."autogen"."water_agg" FROM 
"NOAA_water_database"."autogen"./.*/ GROUP BY time(15m), *
```

The above query runs successfully, but I'm not sure whether influx has considered points from all measurement of **NOAA_water_database** or just last appearing measurement is considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** I'm not sure whether influx has considered points from all measurement of NOAA_water_database or just last appearing measurement is considered.

**A:** I suspect `influxdb` is not aggregating the data from your measurements.

I think it is only aggregating the data from each measurement individually and then for each output write it to your specified measurement and since the resolved `time` of the `mean` operation can possibly be the same, measurement B's result can overwrite measurement A's result.

I derived this theory by doing an experiment using the following dataset;

```
INSERT cpu,host=serverA value=10
INSERT cpu,host=serverA value=20

INSERT cpu2,host=serverA value=5
INSERT cpu2,host=serverA value=15
```

Doing a `SELECT` statement similar to your query above returns;

```
select * FROM "historian"."autogen"./cpu.*/
name: cpu
time                host    value
----                ----    -----
1546511130857357196 serverA 10
1546511132744883738 serverA 20

name: cpu2
time                host    value
----                ----    -----
1546511156629403118 serverA 5
1546511157888695746 serverA 15
```

Then instead of using `mean` I do `sum` to find test the behaviour of influxdb.
I also simplified the query by dropping the `groupBy` operation.

Doing a `sum` gives me;

```
SELECT sum("value") INTO test_sum FROM "historian"."autogen"./.*/ 
name: result
time written
---- -------
0    2
> select * from test_sum;
name: test_sum
time sum
---- ---
0    20
```

Theory: if `influx` is aggregating the data from all measurements, the sum result would not be `20`. It should be `50`. The only way 20 can be derived is from by summing `5 + 15` which is the data from the last measurement.

But when we do the `sum` operation, `influx` did told us 2 rows were written. My theory to this is that, the influx did calculate the sum of the first measurement however as first and second summation's result time is both `0` therefore the 2nd measurement's result would have overwritten the first result's.

**Recommended solution:**
The best tool to do this job is actually influxdb's [kapacitor](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/). It is a great tool because it is fast however it is also extremely to learn.

Alternatively if your dataset isn't huge which I suspect it should be alright since you are `grouping` by 15m. You can write a script in your favourite programming language to read out the data, do the `mean` and then write the data back to `influxdb`.